# For loop run time

Tags: loops, for-loop, integer

I was having trouble understanding the following concepts of how processor speed affects how long a certain loop runs for.

For a computer with a 3GHz processor, and can do 64-bit arithmetic per cycle, for how long will the following loop run?

long long int x;
for(x = 0 x<=0; x--){}

Comment: I hope this could be optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler may optimize this loop out entirely because it may detect that no result is ever used.

But if the loop is actually compiled, a guess at an upper bound on speed might be two cycles per iteration. Yes, the processor is probably superscaler, so it can sometimes execute more than one instruction in a cycle, but on the other hand one instruction is a branch, which tends to break the pipeline.

So, if we guess two cycles, then it will take about a century to run that loop.

```
irb> 2**63/(3*10**9)/60/60/24/7/52 # => 97 years
```

I'm tempted to say that the loop will never finish, as this is much longer than the MTBF for servers, UPS equipment, and power grids, but perhaps you could run it in a VM and checkpoint it periodically. :-)

Of course, there is that Greek fable on the folly of speculation when empirical evidence is available.  Why not run the loop for a small amount of time and then calculate the actual result for 2<sup>63</sup> iterations? The speculation is difficult because few people other than the designers really understand today's complex microarchitectures. There are also many practical problems: does the compiler get to unroll the loop?  Perhaps you should just write it in assembly so you can measure something specific?